# Hide empty folders recursively, ignoring .DS_Store, etc

Tags: bash, terminal, directory, hidden-files, alfred

I'm attempting to write a bash script to hide empty folders recursively within the current directory.

This will ultimately be used as part of an Alfred workflow, allowing me to hide/show extra folders in my default project folder hierarchy. The goal is to keep my sanity when reacquainting myself with a project, but keep folder structure in place so I can keep things consistent from project to project.

I've been experimenting with this terminal command

```
find . -empty -type d -exec chflags hidden {} +
```

This works in theory, but the problem is Mac OS X adds system files to folders that I'd like to consider empty for my purposes.

How can I ignore files like .DS_Store when hiding directories?

Comment: The only possible solution I've come up with is deleting these files first, but then you lose whatever settings they contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c "echo -ne '{}\t'; ls -a1 '{}' | wc -l" \; |   awk -F"\t" '$NF<=3{ system("chflags hidden " $1 ) }'
```

Where $NF<=3 would translate to hide all the folders that have 3 or less items inside, this would typically be:

```
. 
..
.DS_Store
```

You can of course replace that part with something more sophisticated, but you should get the idea.

Or you can precise the search to eliminate specific files with grep, e.g.

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c "echo -ne '{}\t'; ls -a1 '{}' | egrep -v  '^\.(\.?|DS_Store)$' | wc -l" \; |   awk -F"\t" '$NF<=0{ system("chflags hidden " $1 ) }'
```

This will hide folders only if ls returns nothing else but one or more of (./../.DS_Store), as defined within the condition above.

Comment: Wow, that's great! The only issue I'm having is chflags fails to find folders containing spaces.

Comment: This should solve it:
`find . -type d -exec bash -c "echo -ne '{}\t'; ls -a1 '{}' | egrep -v  '^\.(\.?|DS_Store)$' | wc -l" \; |   awk -F"\t" '$NF<=0{ system("chflags hidden \"" $1 "\"" ) }'`

Comment: Thanks for the help! Seems like there's still something going on with recursion. If a folder contains another "empty" folder it is not treated as empty.

Comment: I thought by recursion you meant hiding empty folders from the current level down, not hiding folders with empty subfolders.

This should also hide folders with empty subfolders:
`find . -type d -exec bash -c "echo -ne '{}\t'; ls -al '{}' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1,9-255 | egrep -v  '(^.{10}@.*|^(total|.{11}\.(\.?|DS_Store))$)' | wc -l" \; |   awk -F"\t" '$NF<=0{ system("chflags hidden \"" $1 "\"") }'`

You might need to run the command a few times to get the whole structure straight though...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I essentially want to hide any folder structures that do not contain files. This includes "empty" folders. I will update the question to be clearer.

Comment: Yea, I figured later. That's what the code included in my last comment should do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83682/discussion-between-christian-and-d-k).